# Can the pudb debugger be used on windows?

Tags: python, windows, debugging

Is it possible to us the [pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) python debugger on Windows? If yes, how do you get it installed and working?

When I try and install it using [ez_setup](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py), `python ez_setup.py .\path\to\pudb-unpacked`, it fails with `ImportError: No module named termios`, a module which appears to be for unix only.

I'm using Windows 7, x64.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears the answer is [No, pudb can't be used in Windows](http://www.mail-archive.com/pudb@tiker.net/msg00059.html) at present.

The underlying problem is that pudb relies on urwid, which [expects a unix-like environment](http://www.mail-archive.com/urwid@lists.excess.org/msg00839.html). There is a message in 2006 indicating [3 methods of using urwid on windows](http://www.mail-archive.com/urwid@lists.excess.org/msg00017.html), namely: cygwin, cursesw, and pdcurses. So it there is an avenue of exploration for an adventurer.

Answer (score 5):

I've got pudb running under Cygwin on windows.  I installed it with pip