# Can't see error in code

Tags: python, while-loop

Don't understand what is wrong with the variable contador that returns the max value where it is popped at valormax..

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr): 
    valormax=arr.pop(arr.index(max(arr)))
    contador=0
    i=0
    arr1=sorted(arr)
    while contador<valormax:
        contador+=arr1[i]
        i+1
        if i>len(arr1):
            break

    if contador==valormax:
        return "true"
    else: 
        return "false"
```

By the way does anyone now how to apply the debugger in the powershell in order to see how the loops goes and avoid asking these type of questions through here?

Comment: there is indentation problem

Comment: Use pdb or even better - pudb for debugging.

Comment: i+1 should probably be i+=1, and why don't you use pythons built in boolean `True` and `False` instead of strings?  It'll save you time in the long run.

Comment: import pdb; pdb.set_trace() https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#module-pdb

Comment: I installed pubd on windows and seems that is not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506943/can-the-pudb-debugger-be-used-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly,

```
if contador==valormax:
return "true"
else: 
return "false"
```

should be

```
if contador==valormax:
    return "true"
else: 
    return "false"
```

Second, to avoid fiddling with indexes like `i` (and writing `i+1` instead of `i+=1`), I would replace

```
i=0
arr1=sorted(arr)
while contador<valormax:
    contador+=arr1[i]
    i+1
    if i>len(arr1):
        break
```

By

```
for a in sorted(arr):
    contador+=a
    if contatdor >= valormax:
        break
```

By the way, what's the point of this function ?  Compute whether `max(arr)` equals the sum of all the other elements of `arr` ?

Comment: Well, you know there is a `sum` function, right ?  So you could just write `return sum(arr) == 2*max(arr)`, since `sum(arr)` is `max(arr)` plus the sum of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code might be the issue is in your code format.

From:

```
 if contador==valormax:
 return "true"
 else: 
 return "false"
```

into:

```
if contador==valormax:
    return "true"
else: 
    return "false"
```